# Why is this exception is not printed? Why is it showing an error?

Tags: java, exception

If I am trying to print the value of "a" why is it showing an error? Why has the exception become an error?

```
class Ankit1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        float d,a;
        try
        {
            d=0;
            a=44/d;
            System.out.print("It's not gonna print: "+a); // if exception doesn't occur then it will print and it will go on to the catch block
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException e)
        {
            System.out.println("a:" + a); // why is this an error??
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should post the error to, so we could help you better.

Comment: A follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130800/why-the-exception-is-not-triggered-here

Comment: The follow up is slightly different and slightly related, I'm kinda happy to allow both.

Answer (score 6):

If you see the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The local variable a may not have been initialized

    at your.package.Ankit1.main(Ankit1.java:18)
```

which clearly states `The local variable a may not have been initialized`

You're getting this error as your variable `a` wasn't initialized.

And if you want to print the error message try printing... `e.getMessage()` or `p.printStackTrace()` for complete stack trace.

To fix this simple initialize `a` with some value like this...

```
float a = 0;
```

Comment: after initialization    Undefined variable or class name: ae
         System.out.println("Print hoga"+ae.getMessage());

Comment: I corrected that... try `System.out.println("Print hoga"+e.getMessage()); ` but that too after you initialize `a`

Answer (score 3):

`a` doesn't have any value. As exception happened in `44/d`; statement as no value is in `a` probably.

```
Ankit1.java:14: variable a might not have been initialized
            System.out.println("Print hoga"+a);//why error come??
```

Its because the variable a is not initialized.
 Also there won't be any ArithmeticException thrown for this 44/d statement because it has float operation so there is **no Divide-by-zero Exception Instead Infinity** will be the result.  
For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12130800/586836)

Comment: @Ankit yes. Printing a variable that is not being initialized causes an error.

Answer (score 3):

> "if i am trying to print value of "a" why its showing error?

Because dividing by zero throws an exception before a is initialized.

For printing the error you can print exception message or the whole stacktrace:

```
catch(ArithmeticException e)
{
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` wasn't initialized
initialize default values for `d` and `a`

```
float d = 0.0f;  
float a = 0.0f;
```

or use `Float` instead of `float`

```
Float a = null;
```

Comment: Undefined variable or class name: ae
         System.out.println("Print hoga"+ae.getMessage());//it is showing this error

Answer (score 1):

You define `float d,a;` but you are not initialize them. If you don't also later, before you use them it is a compile time error.
In your `try` you do:
`d=0;

a=44/d;`

But since you initialize them in a `try` and you access them inside the `catch` the compiler complains that `a` is not initialized. If you replaced with `d` you would also get the same error.
To solve this do:

`float d = 0,a = 0;`

**Always** initialize your local variables