# Why is the exception not triggered for division by zero here?

Tags: java, exception

(*This is a follow up question to [Why is this exception is not printed? Why is it showing an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130659/why-is-this-exception-is-not-printed-why-is-it-showing-an-error)*)

Here in the below code why is the ArithmeticException not triggered?

```
class Exp
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        float d,a=1;
        try
        {
            d=0;
            a=44/d; //no exception triggered here.. why?
            System.out.print("It's not gonna print: a="+a); 
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Print exception: "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead the output is:

```
It's not gonna print: a=Infinity
```

What happens?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A division by zero throws an exception for integer values, but not for floating values. This is defined in the [JLS #15.17.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2):

> The result of a floating-point division is determined by the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic:
>   [...]
>
> - Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed infinity. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.

If you change the type of `a` and `d` to `int`, you will get an exception.

Answer (score 7):

Because `Divide by zero` applies to **integers and not floats** as per [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2)

and you would get output as

```
Its not gonna printed a=Infinity
```

since this is computed as `Infinity`

And in case you want to **see an exception** just change

```
a=44/d;
```

to this

```
a=44/0;
```